# Окончание числительных большого количества просмотров

Tags: дефект, предложение, локализация

Для вопросов с большим количеством просмотров, т.е. когда начинает появляться суффикс типа `k`, наблюдается проблема с окончанием числительного:

[image: 6K]

Вытекает видимо из точного числа показов, т.к. при наведении курсора всплывает хинт:

[image: 5863]

Количество показов увеличилось и баг спрятался немного:

[image: 5866]

Но в исходном варианте должно быть всё-таки `6k показов`, а не `6k показа`.

Comment: Уже было: [http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1446/184217](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1446/184217), [http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/368/10105](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/368/10105).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov жалко, что за год+ до сих пор не исправлено.